# Apache Virtual Host setup not working?

Tags: apache2

I had follow this link to setup my first virtual host with apache2 under Ubuntu 12.x.
Looks easy but is not working.

[How to][1]

My internal DNS can resolve the name, but my browsers is not showing me my webpage.
from my LAN, I'm using Ubuntu server no GUI.

Every time I point to my virtual host name, I receive apache default page, I cannot see my custom page.

My docs are under `/home/mydomain/public_html`

This is my settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/example.com/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/example.com/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

The rest of the file is the same.

No, I even try to change the port from `*:80` to `*:81`, restart and don't see apache listen to port `81`.

My localDNS running in other machine works.

What I forget?

Comment: Try putting the Document Root path in quotes `"/home/example.com/public_html"`.  Run `/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S`and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you seem to have forgotten to include the link to the Howto in your question, so it's unclear what you did exactly. Maybe the config item `NameVirtualHost *:80` is missing? It should be specified just once outside of a `VirtualHost` config.